# Document.onclick running twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I'm trying to add a mailto link via javascript to an element within a tooltip. I've had to put the code in a `document.onclick` as the code doesn't run if it's not. So now i have it working but the problem is you need to click twice on the link for it to fire. Is there a way for remove the 2 clicks? If this function isn't within the document.onclick it doesn't work. Thanks in advance..

```
document.onclick = function(){
     jQuery(".gm_popup .email").click(function(){
        var text = jQuery(this).text();
        document.location = "mailto:" + text.trim();
    });
  }
```

Comment: It does not make sense to add a click in a click.... Every click on the page will result in an event being added. You are using jQuery, there is a better way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nailed it

```
$(document).on('click', '.gm_popup .email', function(){
  var text = jQuery(this).text();
  document.location = "mailto:" + text.trim();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than attaching the event to your element on click, just attach it on page load.  Since you are already using jquery:

```
$(function() {
    //Anything you place in here won't be run until the page has loaded
});
```

So, in your case, do something like this

```
$(function() {
    jQuery(".gm_popup .email").click(function(){
        var text = jQuery(this).text();
        document.location = "mailto:" + text.trim();
    });  
});
```

Comment: i gave it a go and it didn't run at all. i just tried to put it in a $(window).load and it worked but still required the double click

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to click the element so the tooltip shows up with a link and then click for the 2nd time in the tooltip link.
Other than that, you can try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".gm_popup .email").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var text = jQuery(this).text();
        document.location = "mailto:" + text.trim();
    });
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: i tried this then nothing was firing. also tried to put it under the document.onclick also with still no luck

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to add the mailto event handler to tooltip link when it be displayed, so you bind the event to the link while document clicked. In such a case, maybe $(".gm_popup .email").on("click", handler) is a better choice.